# Laravel passing parameter to api Resource

Tags: laravel

I'm inside my api `UserResource`:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'offers' => OfferResource::collection($this->offers),
}
```

Question is simple - how can I pass `$this->id` to my `OfferResource` and be able to use it inside `OfferResource` as for example `$user_id`? I've tried to find solution for this, but none of them works for me.

Comment: You can create a method that accepts parameters inside offerreresource model

Comment: can you provide any example?

Comment: Inside the model: `public function test($arg) {dd($arg)}`.
Call it this way: `$model = new MyModel; $model->test("foo")`. If you haven't, you should also take a look at relations.